# Configure nginx to redirect non existing $uri to php file as a GET-parameter

Tags: php, redirect, nginx, get

I'm trying to redirect any url that doesn't point to a file/folder to a php file with the url as an argument to create an url shorter.
This is my current code but the url doesn't seem to get passed to the php file:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /short/index.php?id=$uri;
}
```

Is this code correct and if so, why doesn't it work?

Comment: Your configuration file looks fine. You could temporarily substitute `/short/index.php` with the simple php script `<?php phpinfo();` just to confirm exactly which parameters are being passed to your program.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was that $uri was including a leading / before the argument.
So I just changed my php-script to remove the / and everything worked fine